# Can't move a file into my /opt folder because I don't have permissions

Tags: command-line, permissions

When I try to move my files into `/opt` with the command `mv`, bash says that I don't have permission.

Comment: Please add more information.  Which user account are you using, and are you using sudo.

Comment: I'd suggest that manually moving arbitrary files into /opt is probably the wrong thing to do. If you've got executable files, you should put them in ~/bin (in your home folder). Non-executable files belong elsewhere.

Answer (score 6):

To move a file called *filename* into the `/opt` directory change directories using `cd` into the directory containing filename and run this command:

```
sudo mv filename /opt # preface mv with sudo to move a file into a directory that is owned only by root
```

Comment: I'm suggesting to the user that they not manually move arbitrary files into /opt, but rather put executable files into ~/bin, and non-executables elsewhere.